# How to remove arrow on JMenuItem?

Tags: java, swing, jmenuitem

I need help with JMenuItem. I didn't write any line about arrow on JMenuItem. So how to disable that? Here's the image:

[image: See Image Here]

Comment: Are you sure this is a 'leaf' JMenuItem? Looks more like a submenu. Could you show us your code?

Comment: If you don't want a drop-down list, are you sure JMenu is what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to reproduce the issue.

- Add `JMenuItem` in `JMenu` and then in `JMenuBar`.

sample code: (**No issues**)

```
JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
JMenu menu = new JMenu("A Menu");

JMenu submenu = new JMenu("A submenu");
JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem("Another item");
submenu.add(menuItem);              //comment this line and look the output
menu.add(submenu);

menuBar.add(menu);
```

[image]

---

- Add `JMenu` directly in `JMenuBar` without any `JMenuItem`.

sample code: (**This creates problem**)

```
JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
JMenu menu = new JMenu("A Menu");

JMenu submenu = new JMenu("A submenu");
menu.add(submenu);

menuBar.add(menu);
```

[image]

---

- Add `JMenuItem` directly in `JMenuBar`.

sample code: (**No issues**)

```
JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
JMenu menu = new JMenu("A Menu");

JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem("Another item");
menu.add(menuItem);

menuBar.add(menu);
```

[image]

Now the problem is crystal clear, if it's leaf node then add `JMenuItem` instead of `JMenu` in `JMenuBar`.

[Read more...](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with JavaFX with my MenuItems having arrows all over the place.

Thanks to @Braj response I realized that I was creating my items this way:

```
MenuItem saveMenu = new Menu();
```

instead of

```
MenuItem saveMenu = new MenuItem();
```

This, of course, works in Java thanks to polymorphism but created this side effect in my app. That being said, this can help you better organize your menus using a tree structure like Save > Save to File / Save to DB / Save As...